# Hive auto increment

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, auto-increment, hiveql

I want to create an auto_increment column in Hive. 
I didn't see anything on the hive doc about that but I found that we can used :
UDFRowSequence to make that.

Is there the most recent way to do that or is there a new way, most "easier" ?

I already tried it : so in my Java project, I had created the function like that :

```
private static void createAutoIncrFunction() throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "create function autoincr as \"org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf.UDFRowSequence\"";
    stmt.execute(sql);
}
```

The creation of the function is working.
But now I don't how to create my table with this function I tried :

```
private static void createTableLine() throws SQLException {
    String sql =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS line(id_line INT autoincr(), "
                                                + "uid_ticket VARCHAR(64), "
                                                + "number INT, "
                                                + "kind INT)";
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(sql);
}
```

But It's not working, so my question is: how can I create a table with an auto_increment column and how can I insert data in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is created normally. But while adding, you might use the function created by you.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE increment_table1 (id INT, c1 STRING, c2 STRING, c3 STRING);
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE increment_table1 SELECT incr() AS inc, id, c1, c2 FROM t1;
```

You can use this [link](https://hadooptutorial.info/writing-custom-udf-in-hive-auto-increment-column-hive/) for more information